# Can't disable ionic ios "rubber band" view

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, scroll, rubber-band

On Ionic `2.0.0-beta.37` and iOS `10.1.1` I can't disable rubber banding for my views.

I've this in `config.xml`

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

and this on my `ion-content`

```
<ion-content sroll="false" has-bouncing="false" overflow-scroll="false">
```

but none of these works. Any tip on what to try is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` on my scrolling element solved the issue